# kendo grid export excel removes white space at end : kendo version is 2016.2.714

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I want to export my excel with whitespace same as I am getting it from server.

I am using kendo Save as function

```
kendo.saveAs({ dataURI: workbook.toDataURL(), fileName: 'exportedFile.xlsx' });
```

method to export data to excel file..

I am creating whole work book using

```
 var workbook = new kendo.ooxml.Workbook({
 sheets: [{}]
```

using Jquery.

I am getting data from server like `"Report   "` but when i check it in excel file it does not contain any white space at the end.

Comment: I found that version 2016.2.714 is not supported space at end when I used kendo 2018.1.117 it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that version 2016.2.714 is not supported space at end when I used kendo 2018.1.117 it worked